# are there any good open source WIKIs based on asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wiki

I am looking for a good WIKI software to host on Windows. Are there any based on ASP.NET MVC that have been built? I can't seem to find any by googling.

Comment: Not sure if it's MVC, but the obvious ASP.NET wiki system to point out is [ScrewTurn](http://www.screwturn.eu/).

Comment: Mr. Google told me about this one here: http://tavaresstudios.com/Blog/page/ASPNET-MVC-Wiki-Sample.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one I could find was MVCWiki on Source Forge. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to run with .Net 4.0 MVC2. Also the last commit was done over a year ago, so the project might be dead.

Answer (score 0):

A new mvc4-based wiki engine has been released at http://lynxwiki.codeplex.com with a running version of the engine at http://www.sapientier.com:88/LynxWiki/WikiTopic/Page/WikiRoot/WikiDir/HomePage

This is a full-featured wiki with many of the features of MediaWiki plus it has the capability for dynamic content by using embedded IronPython scripting.